How to run a YIP file?
I was tasked with connecting with the Yaskawa Smart Pendant, and need to enable this, I will need to enable Development Access. This feature is disabled by factory default but can be enabled by downloading and installing the "Activate Development Access" yip. How can I run a yip file so that there will be a connection?
